# storing arraylist, phonebookdemo program(Need two more lines)?

Tags: java

I need to fill in the blanks on a phone book entry and phone book demo class. I've filled them all in except for two of them in the demo class, the parts that I need to fill in are represented by question marks.

PhoneBookEntry:

```
public class PhoneBookEntry
{
   private String name;         // Person's name
   private String phoneNumber;  // Person's phone number

   /**
    * The constructor initializes the person's name
    * and phone number.
    */

   public PhoneBookEntry(String n, String pn)
   {
      name = n;
      phoneNumber = pn;
   }

   /**
    * The setName method sets the person's name.
    */

   public void setName(String n)
   {
      name = n;
   }

   /**
    * setPhoneNumber method sets the person's 
    * phone number.
    */

   public void setPhoneNumber(String pn)
   {
      phoneNumber = pn;
   }

   /**
    * The getName method returns the person's 
    * name.
    */

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   /**
    * The getPhoneNumber method returns the
    * person's phone number.
    */

   public String getPhoneNumber()
   {
      return phoneNumber;
   }
}
```

I filled in the blanks on that one, in the PhoneBookDemo I don't have a clue on what to put in the spaces with the question marks:

```
public class PhoneBookDemo
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      // Constant for the numer of entries.
      final int NUM_ENTRIES = 5;

      // Create an ArrayList to hold PhoneBookEntry objects.
      ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> list = 
         new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>();

      // Tell the user what's about to happen.
      System.out.println("I'm going to ask you to enter " +
                         NUM_ENTRIES + " names and phone numbers.");
      System.out.println();

      // Create and store PhoneBookEntry objects in the ArrayList.
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++)
      {
         ???????
         System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println("Here's the data you entered:");

      // Display the data stored in the ArrayList.
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
      {
          ????????????
      }
   }

   /**
    * The getEntry method creates a PhoneBookEntry object
    * populated with data entered by the user and returns
    * a reference to the object.
    */

   public static PhoneBookEntry createEntry()
   {
      // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Variables to hold a person's name and
      // phone number.
      String name;
      String phoneNumber;

      // Get the data.
      System.out.print("Enter a person's name: ");
      name = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter that person's phone number: ");
      phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();

      // Create a PhoneBookEntry object.
      PhoneBookEntry entry = new PhoneBookEntry(name, phoneNumber);

      // Return a reference to the object.
      return entry;
   }

   /**
    * The displayEntry method displays the data stored
    * in a PhoneBookEntry object.
    */

   public static void displayEntry(PhoneBookEntry entry)
   {
      System.out.println("------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Name: " + entry.getName());
      System.out.println("Phone number: " + entry.getPhoneNumber());
   }
}
```

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/108326)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two methods in your code which are not used

```
  // Create and store PhoneBookEntry objects in the ArrayList.
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++)
  {
     list.add (createEntry());
  }
```

and

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
      displayEntry(list.get(i));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create and store : call the method that create an instance, and add it to the list

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++){
      PhoneBookEntry create = createEntry();
      list.add(create);
      System.out.println();
   }
   ```
2. Display : call the `displayEntry` method on each element, but the best way is to implement the `toString()` method in the `PhoneBookEntry` class and use a `System.out.println(list.get(i));`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
       displayEntry(list.get(i));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following code:

```
public class PhoneBookDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Constant for the numer of entries.
        final int NUM_ENTRIES = 5;

        // Create an ArrayList to hold PhoneBookEntry objects.
        ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> list
                = new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>();

        // Tell the user what's about to happen.
        System.out.println("I'm going to ask you to enter "
                + NUM_ENTRIES + " names and phone numbers.");
        System.out.println();

        // Create and store PhoneBookEntry objects in the ArrayList.
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++) {
            list.add(createEntry());
        }

        System.out.println("Here's the data you entered:");

        // Display the data stored in the ArrayList.
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            displayEntry(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * The getEntry method creates a PhoneBookEntry object populated with data
     * entered by the user and returns a reference to the object.
     */
    public static PhoneBookEntry createEntry() {
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Variables to hold a person's name and
        // phone number.
        String name;
        String phoneNumber;

        // Get the data.
        System.out.print("Enter a person's name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter that person's phone number: ");
        phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Create a PhoneBookEntry object.
        PhoneBookEntry entry = new PhoneBookEntry(name, phoneNumber);

        // Return a reference to the object.
        return entry;
    }

    /**
     * The displayEntry method displays the data stored in a PhoneBookEntry
     * object.
     */
    public static void displayEntry(PhoneBookEntry entry) {
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name: " + entry.getName());
        System.out.println("Phone number: " + entry.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}




public class PhoneBookEntry {

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public PhoneBookEntry() {
    }

    public PhoneBookEntry(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the phoneNumber
     */
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param phoneNumber the phoneNumber to set
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not hold phone book's entires apart from phone bool. Do incapsulate this logic into the phone book:

```
public final class PhoneBook {

    private final Map<String, Entry> entries = new TreeMap<>();

    public void add(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        entries.put(name, new Entry(name, phoneNumber));
    }

    public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
        return entries.values().iterator();
    }

    public static final class Entry {

        private final String name;
        private final String phoneNumber;

        public Entry(String name, String phoneNumber) {
            this.name = name;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can define method, that ask user for phone book entries and retrieves the whole phone book instead of list of phone book's entreis:

```
public static PhoneBook getPhoneBook(int totalEntries) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

        System.out.println("I'm going to ask you to enter " + totalEntries + " names and phone numbers.");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalEntries; i++) {
            System.out.println("Entry " + i + ':');
            System.out.print("Enter a person's name: ");
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter that person's phone number: ");
            String phoneNumber = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            phoneBook.add(name, phoneNumber);
        }

        return phoneBook;
    }
}
```

Finally you can use this method to get a phone book and print all entires:

```
final int totalEntries = 5;

getPhoneBook(totalEntries).iterator().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Name: " + entry.getName());
    System.out.println("Phone number: " + entry.getPhoneNumber());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//iterate over number of entries        
 for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++)
          {
       //add to the phonebooklist
            list.add (createEntry());
             System.out.println();
          }

          System.out.println("Here's the data you entered:");

          // Display the data stored in the ArrayList.
          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
          {
                //display entry  from list

               displayEntry(list.get(i));
//use display entry method for display 
          }
```

Comment: With some explanations this answer would be even better